Examples of cotopoi each of whose internal logic is indeed paraconsistent.
Looking at this MO question, this MSE question, and their answers, it looks like some progress has been made in 2015, after the MSE question.
Instead of ask whether a category can have a paraconsistent logic, I'm wondering . . .

What examples are there of cotopoi with paraconsistent internal logics?

So it's specific to the duals of topoi, known as cotopoi.

Apparently, it's not as simple as saying that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a topos with an internal logic that breaks the law of excluded middle, then $\mathcal C^{\operatorname{op}}$ is a cotopos whose internal logic is paraconsistent.  At least, that's the impression I get from the answers referenced above. I could be wrong here.

I don’t think it’s a settled matter whether a cotopos has paraconsistent internal logic. As mentioned in the linked MO answer, the naïve approach runs into trouble.
